# Are there any events to run something before and after a task is completed in JakeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jake

I'm trying to run something before and after a task is completed in JakeJS and I'm not sure how to do it.

Currently, I need to attach the function to each task like this and it's tedious.

```
var complete = function() {
    // Do something when a task is completed
}

task("someTask", function() {
    // Do something
})
.addListener("complete", complete)

task("anotherTask", function() {
    // Do something
})
.addListener("complete", complete)
```

I can probably wrap task by yet another function but that's just a ugly hack so I wonder if I can do something like this.

```
jake.addListener("afterTaskCompleted", function() {
    // Do something when a task is completed
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake has a start event so what I did is iterated over the collection and checked whether it's a *task*; if it is then I've attached the handler to the *completed* event.

```
jake.addListener("start", function (e) {
    _.forOwn(jake.Task, function(task, name) {
        if (task.name && task.prereqs && name !== "__root__") {
            task.addListener("complete", function() { console.log() })
        }
    })
})
```

p.s. I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to iterate over the collection.